# How to know if all elements of an array belongs to a range

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to know if all elements of an array of numbers belong to a range.
For example:

```
let arr = [1,2,3];
belongs to the range 1-10
In this case, should return true
```

Comment: Use the `arr.every()` method.

Comment: For freshman, uses one simple for-loop will be a better practice, and straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to test if each element of an array matches a condition.

```js
let arr = [1,2,3];
let start = 1, end = 10;
console.log(arr.every(x=>x>=start&&x<=end));
```